# How to copy the string that remains after using strncpy

Tags: c, string, strncmp

I am learning C and want to learn how I can copy the remaining characters leftover in the string after using `strncpy`. I would like to have the string `Hello World` broken down into two separate lines.

```
For example:

int main() {
    char someString[13] = "Hello World!\n";
    char temp[13];

    //copy only the first 4 chars into string temp
    strncpy(temp, someString, 4);

    printf("%s\n", temp);          //output: Hell
}
```

How do I copy the remaining characters (`o World!\n`) in a new line to print out?

Comment: Given a pointer `p` that points to the first character of a string, do you know how to write an expression that points to the fifth character of a string?

Comment: Don't use strncpy() until you know what it does.

Comment: `strncpy()` is perverse - it doesn't really copy the string - it ***fills the target buffer***.  It starts with the input string, and if the input string isn't long enough, it fills the entire rest of the buffer with `'\0'` characters.  If the input string is long enough to fill the target buffer, `strncpy()` fills the buffer with characters from the input string ***and doesn't `'\0'` terminate the target buffer.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `char someString[13]` , you don't have enough space for the string `Hello World\n`, since you have 13 characters but you need at least size of 14, one extra byte for the `NULL byte`, `'\0'`. You better off let the compiler decide the size of the array, wouldn't be prone to **UB** that way.

To answer your question, you can just use `printf()` to display the remaining part of the string, you only need to specify a pointer to the element you want to start at.

In addition, `strncpy()` doesn't `NULL` terminate `tmp`, you are gonna have to do that manually if you want functions like `printf()` or `puts()` to function properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char someString[] = "Hello World!\n";
    char temp[14];

    strncpy(temp,someString,4);

    temp[4] = '\0'; /* NULL terminate the array */

    printf("%s\n",temp);
    printf("%s",&someString[4]); /* starting at the 4th element*/

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The one thing you should learn about `strncpy` is **never use this function**.

The semantics of `strncpy` are counter-intuitive and poorly understood by most programmers. It is confusing and error prone. In most cases, it does not do the job.

In your case, it copies the first 4 bytes and leaves the rest of `temp` uninitialized. You might have known this, but still invoked undefined behavior by passing `temp` to `printf` as a string argument.

If you want to manipulate memory, use `memcpy` and `memmove` and be careful about null terminators.

As a matter of fact, the string `"Hello world!\n"` has 13 characters and a null terminator, requiring 14 bytes in memory. Defining `char someString[13] = "Hello World!\n";` is legal but it makes `someString` not a C string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char someString[14] = "Hello World!\n";
    char temp[14];

    memcpy(temp, someString, 4); //copy only the first 4 chars into string temp
    temp[4] = '\0';              // set the null terminator
    printf("%s\n", temp);        //output: Hell\n

    strcpy(temp + 4, someString + 4);  // copy the rest of the string
    printf("%s\n", temp);        //output: Hello World!\n\n

    memcpy(temp, someString, 14); //copy all 14 bytes into array temp
    printf("%s\n", temp);        //output: Hello World!\n\n

    // Note that you can limit the number of characters to output for a `%s` argument:
    printf("%.4s\n", temp);      //output: Hell\n
    return 0;
}
```

You can read more about `strncpy` here:

- https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/stop-using-strncpy-already/
- http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html
- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=36773
- [What is the best alternative to strncpy()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41869803/what-is-the-best-alternative-to-strncpy)

Answer (score 0):

In your case you could try something like:

```
char   temp2[13];
strncpy(temp2, &someString[4], 9);
```

By the way you are missing a semicolon:

```
char   someString[13] = "Hello World!\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to push your pointer of `n` character and copy the `size - n` caractere:

```c
size_t n = 4; // nunmber caractere to copy first 
size_t size = 13; // string length

char someString[size] = "Hello World!\n";
char temp[size];
char last[size - n]; // the string that contain the reste

strncpy(temp, someString, n); // your copy
strncpy(last, someString + n, 13 - n); // copy of reste of the string
```